# Dev C++ sdl library setpixel or putpixel example code request

Tags: c++

I am new to SDL library and I want to change colour of pixels. I need like this code which can be used in windows.h

```
COLORREF c=RGB(0, 0, 255);

SetPixel(hdc, PlotX[i], PlotY[i], c);
```

It is very simple. But windows.h library is a bit complex. And I need also console for debugging. SDL seems simple but I didn't know how can do Setpixel with it.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: What is the **error** you are taking, or what exactly you are asking for ?

Comment: Start with opening a window. There are a lot of good tutorials on this.

Comment: I am trying to build some kind of plotter library. I do not know how can I do it with SDL library. I will not use windows.h ,I will use SDL.h

Answer (score 1):

According to [Windows Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setpixel);

> The SetPixel function sets the pixel at the specified coordinates to the specified color.

And the parameters of the SetPixel function;

> hdc = A handle to the device context.
>
> x =   The x-coordinate, in logical units, of the point to be set.
>
> y =   The y-coordinate, in logical units, of the point to be set.
>
> color =  The color to be used to paint the point. To create a COLORREF
>   color value, use the RGB macro.

Here is a sample code how can you use this function to set it at the specified coordinates ( we specify it via `x` and `y` parameters of the `SetPixel` function) and to the specified color ( with the `color` parameter )

```
#include <windows.h>

static HWND sHwnd;
static COLORREF redColor=RGB(255,0,0);
static COLORREF blueColor=RGB(0,0,255);
static COLORREF greenColor=RGB(0,255,0);

void pixelSet(int x,int y,COLORREF& color){
    if(sHwnd != NULL){
        HDC hdc=GetDC(sHwnd);
        SetPixel(hdc,x,y,color);
        ReleaseDC(sHwnd,hdc);
    }

}
```

And you can call this `pixelSet()` function later in your code such as;

```
pixelSet(100, 100, blueColor);
```